# stream video file as bytes into stdin

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, pipe, stdin

I am creating a process in which python opens a video file, and streams it into the stdin of an ffmpeg command. I think I have the right idea, but the way that the file is being opened is not working with stdin. Here is my code so far:

```
def create_pipe():

    return Popen([    'ffmpeg',
                      '-loglevel', 'panic',
                      '-s', '1920x1080',
                      '-pix_fmt', 'yuvj420p',
                      '-y',
                      '-f', 'image2pipe',
                      '-vcodec', 'mjpeg',
                      '-r', self.fps,
                      '-i', '-',
                      '-r', self.fps,
                      '-s', '1920x1080',
                      '-f', 'mov',
                      '-vcodec', 'prores',
                      '-profile:v', '3',
                      '-aspect', '16:9', '-y',
                      'output_file_name' + '.mov'], stdin=PIPE)



in_pipe = create_pipe()
with open("~/Desktop/IMG_1973.mov", "rb") as f:
    in_pipe.communicate(input=f)
```

This yields the error:

`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader'`

What would be the right way to open/stream a video file into this pipe? I also needs to be a stream, rather than reading the whole thing into memory.

PS. please ignore that I could natively open the file in ffmpeg... I am creating a wrapper, and it's better if I can control the input.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure the input format can be piped. For ISO BMFF the `moov` atom has to be at the beginning of the file for this to work.

If it's pipeable then use a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to read the file and pipe it to the subprocess:

```
def read_bytes(input_file, read_size=8192):
    """ read 'read_size' bytes at once """
    while True:
        bytes_ = input_file.read(read_size)
        if not bytes_:
            break
        yield bytes_


def main():
    in_pipe = create_pipe()

    with open("in.mov", "rb") as f:
        for bytes_ in read_bytes(f):
            in_pipe.stdin.write(bytes_)

    in_pipe.stdin.close()
    in_pipe.wait()
```